# Android activity background turns black on older versions

Tags: java, android

When I start a new popup activity (just a scaled activity), everything works fine on the newest android version, but the background slowly turns black on v26 (Android 8.0).

I use `getWindow().setLayout()` to scale the activity.

My theme:

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This is how the activity looks after it slowly went darker:

[image: popup activity with black background]

I found this problem nowhere on StackOverflow, does somebody know about it?

Comment: Try setting android:windowIsTranslucent to false.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason**

It seems to be an issue with some Android versions.

There are 2 thinks that are not supported together:

`android:windowIsTranslucent` and `android:orientation`.

If one translucent Activity is above an Activity with a different orientation, there is nothing Android can display.

But the developers of Android did not enable it if both orientations are **the same**, but rather just disabled changing the orientation completely and only enabled setting it to the one of its parent (default). This behaviour was changed in newer versions.

**Solution**

Either use

```
android:windowIsTranslucent = false
```

or leave out

```
android:orientation
```

in your popup-Activity.